# Proving a set is closed using a continuous map

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}$
$\newcommand{\dist}{\text{dist}}$
Let $F$ be a closed set of $\R^n$.
Given $x\in\R^n$, I have already shown that the set
$$r(x) = \{y\in F : \|x-y\|=\dist(x,F)\}$$
is a nonempty set. In that way, we define a function $r:\R^n\to {\cal P}(F)$ and I'm interested in look at the "graphic" of $r$.

Let $A=\{(x,y)\in\R^n\times F : y\in r(x)\}$. Using that the map $x\mapsto\dist(x,F)$ is continuous, how can I prove that $A$ is closed?

I've been trying look at $A$ as a preimage of a closed subset of $\R$ under the map $x\mapsto\dist(x,F)$, but without success.

Any help?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think sequences. Let $(x,y) \in \overline{A}$. Then there is $((x_n,y_n))_{n \geq 0}\subseteq A$ such that $(x_n,y_n) \to (x,y)$. So, we know that $y_n \in r(x_n)$ for all $n$ and we want to prove that $y \in r(x)$. Ok, then we know that

$$\|x_n-y_n\| = {\rm dist}(x_n,F)$$for all $n$, hence $$\lim \|x_n-y_n\| = \lim {\rm dist}(x_n,F).$$But the norm $\|\cdot\|$ and the distance ${\rm dist}(\cdot, F)$ are continuous maps, so they commute with $\lim$ and follows that $$\|x-y\| = {\rm dist}(x,F).$$This means $y \in r(x)$, as wanted (sure, if $y_n \in F$ for all $n$ and $F$ is closed, this also implies that $y \in F$, so no problems).

Answer (score 2):

$$\newcommand{\dist}{\operatorname{dist}}A = \{x,y\in \Bbb R^n \times F : \|x-y\| = \dist(x,F)\}.$$
Let $$\phi:(x,y)\mapsto\dist(x,F) - \|x - y\|.$$ $\phi$ is a continuous function from $\Bbb R^n\times F$ to $\Bbb R$, and $A = \phi^{-1}(\{0\})$.